# How can I fix my jsonp callback to address the "unexpected token" error, using angularjs $http?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, google-apps-script, jsonp

The specs for receiving jsonp from google apps script are not causing an "unexpected token" in the return data.

I'm using angularjs $http.jsonp -  it doesn't like the syntax ?prefix=? at the end of my url to the google apps script.

This works fine with jQuery, but I'm trying to go all angular with this app.  Here is a [fiddle I forked from a previous user](http://jsfiddle.net/4JRqm/).  Here is the request, which is fine:

```
function jsonp_example($scope, $http) {
$scope.doRequest = function() {
    var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyTnhcsnyXKJqZdF8yAppVQjXX935J9-YTJOHyf7jkea16gSsOA/dev?prefix=?";

    $http.jsonp(url);
};
```

Have console open, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function jsonp_example($scope, $http) {
    $scope.doRequest = function() {
        var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyTnhcsnyXKJqZdF8yAppVQjXX935J9-YTJOHyf7jkea16gSsOA/dev?prefix=JSON_CALLBACK";

        $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) { alert(data) })
    };
}
```

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sc0ttyd/7MUty/3/